# Xcode failed to run tests

Tags: ios, xcode

When running unit tests in Xcode I get the following console output:

> Failed to run tests: Timeout out trying to establish connection to IDE.test

Why don't my tests run, and how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to go to `Xcode > Preferences > Locations` and change back `Command Line Tools` to the correct version of Xcode. I had previously changed this value to do something else and forgot to change it back.

Comment: Same problem here, but Command Line Tools is OK at Xcode 9.0 and still facing the issue. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

In my case it seems XCTest is waiting for some kind of expectation that never fulfilled:

```
 <XCTWaiter: 0x1c4204a80, state: XCTWaiterStateFailed> reporting timed out failure with Transport for IDE session acquired
```

I guess it's related to Xcode 10 beta.Anyway, restart everything solved the problem.

- Clean Project
- Delete test host app
- Restart computer
- Restart iPhone